# Auto Layout "Add New Constraints" not interactive in Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7, autolayout

I am updating an application for iOS 7 and have decided to use Auto Layout.

When I try to add constraints to **any** of the elements in the below screenshot :

[image]

**i.e.** `View Controller`, `Table View`, `View`, `Table View Section`, `Table View Cell`, `Content View`, `Label`.

I am unable do to so, as **no item** in the `Add New Constraints` **panel** ( as seen below ) is interactive.
(Apart from the `Update Frames` Item)

[image]

In my attempts to resolve this issue I have researched that

"When using Auto Layout you may no longer set the frame of a view directly. This line either has no effect, or it may directly interfere with what Auto Layout is doing."

also

"When setting the contentSize of a scrollview with Auto Layout, the content size is automatically derived from the constraints that you set on its child views."

The problem is still there when I update the `ViewContoller` code to accommodate this advice.

Comment: I don't think you can set the constraints for View Controller. You can only set constraints for UIView, UITableView or for some other items in your view controller. But your image shows that you selected the view Controller and trying to set constraints on it .

Comment: @Priyatham51, I updated the question for clarity. It is the case for any of the elements in the first screenshot.

Comment: Okay try selecting your TableView on the storyboard and when you open the add constraints enter some value in the box which is right below the "Add new constraints". What I observed when I am adding constraints is , it will be inactive in the beginning. but when you enter some value in the boxes the "Add constraint" button will be enabled .

Comment: I highly recommend reading through the apples autolayout guide at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH13-SW1. It is pretty straing forward and will walk you through the "magic" so that things appear when you need them.

Comment: @Priyatham51, Updated the question again for clarity. No item in the Panel is interactive i.e. I can not "enter some value in the boxes " as the boxes are not interactive

Comment: @RayTrask I have. However, the very first part shows the Panel interactive. And I have not seen a situation that is comparable. i.e. Nothing being interactive

Comment: @Ríomhaire I am in the same situation as you. Did you find how to solve that ?

Comment: No @HpTerm I didn't. Please let me know if you find a way. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar issue. I was able to add constraints for items on a Table View Cell - Content View (e.g. UILabel, UIImageView), once I switched the Table View Cell Style to Custom.

[image]

If I added images or UILabels on top of a default Table View Cell type (e.g. Subtitle), I could position them on the Content View, but couldn't set constraints on them.

Changing to Custom Table View Cell Style was the solution for me.

Comment: Doesn't work if your UICollectionViewCell has a ContentView (box you can select in UI Builder which adds contentView to your view stack, below the cell parent.  But once you take away contentView, a whole list of other problems begins happening.  It's all very counterintuitive and Apple should fix it.

Answer (score 3):

To set the constraints you need to select the items and then set the constraints with either the constraints menu or with ctrl+drag.

However, there is no way to set constraints for a `tableViewController` as it is a already completely set up.

Comment: So there is no way at all to add constraints to a `tableViewController`? I've been looking for this answer for hours lol

Answer (score 1):

There might be set Autoresizing Mask as layout in Size inspector.
Try switching it to Constraints:

[image: Select Constraints]